# loop through :eq() selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

not working attempt : http://jsfiddle.net/ahrxvtaa/

I want to get 3, 6, 9 etc.. note that I use .css() just to see the result, please don't comment u can selector using css.

```
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
```

my js

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).eq(3).css('font-weight','bold');   
}
```

Comment: `$(this)` is a single element, not the set of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like

```js
$('.item').filter(function(idx) {
  return idx > 2 && idx % 2 == 1
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
```

---

or if all these items are children of 1 parent and there are no other elements between them then use the [:nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```js
$('.item:nth-child(2n + 4)').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

```css
.item:nth-child(2n + 4) {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about I want to jump 3 from item 1? to select 4, 6 and so on?

Comment: @user3522892 you want to select 1, 4, 7,... or 1, 4, 6,... then what is the sequence you are looking for

Comment: actually what I'm trying to do is this http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8319/embedded/result/

4,6,8 should be margin-top -100px.. I do it manually because mansory doesn't work in my case

Comment: @user3522892 see the update to the second solution if that fits to your need

Comment: @user3522892 using the second solution there is no need to use jQuery... you can do it using css only

Comment: How about the reverse? odd number

Comment: 3,5,7.. I'm confused how your previous code work.. it work but I just can't understand

Comment: @user3522892 which solution did you opt for

Comment: pls don't update your code, u did a favor to me, but now I want to do the reverse side, which is 3,5,7..

Comment: js version? because I have to use js.

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery 1.9 and above

```js
$('.item:nth-of-type(3n)').css('font-weight','bold');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need `:nth-of-type(3n)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` argument with `.each()`:

```
$('.item').each(function(index){
    if (index % 3 === 2) {
         $(this).css('font-weight','bold');   
    }
}
```

You could also use `.filter()` like this:

```
$('.item').filter(function(index) {
    return index % 3 === 2;
}).css('font-weight','bold');
```

As was pointed out, note that index of 0 is your item 1, index of 1 is your item 2, index 2 is your item 3, so to get 3,6,9 we look for a remainder of 2.

Comment: I think all of us made a mess in the modulus operator... it should be `index % 3 === 2`

Comment: @alexfreiria http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dgzj70e1/1/ - OP want to select 3, 6.... not 1, 4...

Comment: @ArunPJohny - yep, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.item:nth-of-type(3n)').css('font-weight','bold');
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is a good idea, this is for if the sequence isn't as predictable.  You can pass in an array of what you are looking for.

```
var idx = [3,6,9];

for (var i = 0; i < idx.length; i++) {
   /* Subtract one 1 since it is a 0 based index... */
  $('.item').eq(idx[i]-1).css('font-weight','bold');  
};
```

or do the same thing with an each loop...

```
idx.each(function(i){
   $('.item').eq(i-1).css('font-weight','bold');
});
```